# Extracting different data from the same table as different fields with additional tables as lookups

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have two tables. One gives me basic information about demographics. One of the categories in my demographics table is a subset of people, which is housed in ATID 530 (there are several hundred different ATIDs) of this table:

[image]

As you can see the PK of this table is ADefID. My other table uses this as a FK. It houses indexes to additional definitions for records in the original table. However those additional definitions are also just records in the original table. The second table just provides pointers.

[image]

So if we pick a record, let's say ADefID=4684423, and look it up in the second table, we are returned this:

[image]

The CategoryADefID will then point back to the original table's ADefID for another record:

[image]

(note the ATID of this ADefID differs from the original ADefID that this is related to)

So. Let's say I want to pull out a set of records from the first row, say

```
WHERE ATID = 530 AND CycleID = 9600
```

But I also want to pull the ADesc (and maybe ADEValue) from the related definition as a separate field.

So the end result would look sort of like this:

[image]

I understand enough to make the join to the second table and return the CategoryADefID, but I dont know how to use that to call back to another ADefID in the original table. The other limitation is that I would use the ATID field in the WHERE clause (ATID=530) and the related definition will have a different ATID.

Comment: It would be easy if you post table schema and expected result instead of images.

Comment: I think you should really post your table definitions to get back a meaningful answer and avoid speculation.

Comment: Noted, however the second table is not in any of the diagrams and I have limited access to these databases so I did what I could

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add another join back to the original table:

```
 Select *
 From tableA a
   join tableB b on b.ADefID=a.ADefID
   join tableA a2 on a2.ADefID = b.CategoryADefID  
 Where a.ADefID = 4684423
```